# how to add pointers to functions (that have parameters) without parameters and call them later with custom parameters C++

Tags: c++, lambda, void-pointers, std-function

I'm gonna try to keep this short. As much as I can.

I have a Spell class which is mostly duration, cooldown, damage, type of damage, etc..
I have SpellManager class which is supposed to instantiate spells, give them to players or enemies and keep track of every (pointer) spell instantiated. Every spell has 3 effects. Like fireball has (damage over time, aoe, and something else) - so different abilities with different prameters.

I have something like

```
vector<function<void()>> _spell_effects;
```

in my Spell.h and have a function

```
void Spell::SetSpellEffects(vector<function<void()>> spell_effects) {
    _spell_effects = spell_effects;
}
```

Which sets the effects to instance of the spell after being instantiated by Manager which works like this

```
void SpellManager::CreateSpell(Character* spell_owner, ESpellID spell_id) {

    Spell* spell = Spell::CreateSpell(spell_id);
    string spell_name = GameplayStatics::GetEnumString(spell_id);
    map<string, Spell*> spell_instance;
    spell_instance[spell_name] = spell;

    if (dynamic_cast<PlayerCharacter*>(spell_owner) != nullptr) {
        _instanced_spells.push_back(spell_instance);
    }
    else {
        _instanced_enemy_spells.push_back(spell_instance);
    }

    GameplayStatics::AddSpellToCharacter(spell_owner, spell);
    
    AddSpellEffects(spell);
}

void SpellManager::AddSpellEffects(Spell* spell) {


    CharacterData data(ECharacterClass::BARBARIAN);
    PlayerCharacter* player = new PlayerCharacter(data.GetCharacterData(), data.GetPlayerAttributeData());

    CharacterData enemy_data(ECharacterClass::ENEMY);
    EnemyCharacter* enemy = new EnemyCharacter(enemy_data.GetCharacterData());
    enemy->name = "dzura";

    vector<Character*> enemies;
    enemies.push_back(enemy);

    vector<function<void()>> _effects;
    
    function<void()> Fireball_Default = [this, player, enemies]() {
        this->Fireball_Default(player, enemies);
    };
    _effects.push_back(Fireball_Default);

    function<void()> Fireball_Level2 = [this]() {
        this->Fireball_Level2();
    };
    _effects.push_back(Fireball_Level2);

    function<void()> Fireball_Level3 = [this]() {
        this->Fireball_Level3(5);
    };
    _effects.push_back(Fireball_Level3);

    spell->SetSpellEffects(_effects);

}
```

so in main i can call them like this

```
    CharacterData data(ECharacterClass::BARBARIAN);
    PlayerCharacter* player = new PlayerCharacter(data.GetCharacterData(), data.GetPlayerAttributeData());

    SpellManager spell_manager(player);

    spell_manager.CreateSpell(player, SPELL_FIREBALL);

    _enemies.push_back(enemy);

    player->GetActives()[0]->InvokeEffect(1);
```

The spell manager then keeps track of pointers to Spell and handles everything else.
Now with InvokeEffect(1) I can Invoke the effect of the spell 1-3 but they are always called with the same parameters i provided in lambdas. My question is. Could someone refactor the code, tell me how to Instantiate a Spell, then add 3 void functions to it in SpellManager (thats where they're defined), then pass that vector to instance of Spell, and call them at user input with InvokeEffect(1-3) BUT also with custom parameters?

I tried many things I tried different data structures I tried adding the Spells' Effects directly to Spell, I either couldn't get it to work or to compile. This provided code works only with starting data.
Should I somehow pass these in the constructor of the spell? How would I do that? How would I call the spells?
Some of the data structures I used

```
using Function = std::function<void(SpellManager&, vector<any>)>;

vector<map<string, vector<void(*)()>>> _effect_map;
```

and these ones work, where I keep track

```
vector<map<string, Spell*>> _instanced_spells;

vector<map<string, Spell*>> _instanced_enemy_spells;

vector<pair<int, pair<string, Spell*>>> _active_spells;
```

I can change whatever it takes in my design, I need this to work.

Comment: Off-topic: manual use of `new` is concerning.

Comment: How do you know what parameters to pass to the spell effect? I.e. how does the line `player->GetActives()[0]->InvokeEffect(1, arg1, arg2);` know that it needs two args (and their types)?

Comment: Ever consider creating classes and overload `operator()`, using the members of the class as the "parameters"?  This basically moves the parameters to the members instead of at the call site.

Comment: *so different abilities with different prameters.* -- There is too much to unpack with all of what you are trying to describe, but if the issue is that you want to call a function with different parameters, then [see this example](https://godbolt.org/z/c3c5Gx8qT).

Comment: I'm not trying to use a different TYPE of parameter or a different SET of parameters. im just saying some functions have 0 some have 1, some have several parameters.
And if I call them the way described in this code it allways calls for example the Firebal_Default, it will always call the function with Player and Enemy vector provided when declaring lambda! I just want to be able to call a function wtih say different target. Fireball_Blast(Character* Target), and that I can change Target, not that its the one used when declaring lambda. I use new cause it was workaround. Why is it downvoted?

Comment: @Caleth I can use Vector<any> ? I can use var args? besides I know when calling the function how many parameters it has. So if a player decides to use buff I know I only need Player reference, If it chooses to cast chain lightning I know i have to use vector<enemy*> reference. Its not abuout calling the function with different amount of arguments its wih calling it wiht DIFFERENT NUMBERS. The way i defined it with lambda it will always call 5, and it will always call the same pointers I passed to it during declaration!

Comment: @crvenkapavica -- It would be better if you just boil down your issue by using very simple types, and a very simple example that everyone can understand what the issue is.  Instead of mentioning `vector<enemy*>` as opposed to a `Player`, change that to `int` and `double`.  Those are also different types.

Comment: *I'm not trying to use a different TYPE of parameter or a different SET of parameters. im just saying some functions have 0 some have 1, some have several parameters.* -- Maybe it's me, but isn't this *exactly* what "different set of parameters" is?  A differing number of parameters is still a "different set of parameters".

Comment: I want to be able to create a Spell instance of a class; then in another class I want to assign a "callback" a void function. some will take 0 parameters, some will take several. 
and in the Spell class I want a vector where pointers to those functions are stored so i can call those functions in the vector. 
if i do this
    function<void()> Fireball_Level3 = [this]() {
        this->Fireball_Level3(5);
    };
then Firebal_level3 always calls with parameter int = 5. How can I assign pointers to functions which are defined in SpellManager to a vector declared in Spell.h and call them?

Comment: When you are calling those functions, *how* will the calling code know what parameters to pass? Where does that knowledge come from?

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed the problem using std::function<void(param1, param2, param3)> instead of void pointer and mainstereaming each function where it passes the instigator, the target(s) and a pointer to a params struct which can hold as many parameters a sneeded. now when they all have the same signature its easy to solve.